# Function running twice in console

Tags: c++, function

Basically, whenever I run this program in console to test it, my Menu() function gets called and when I give input, it prints the whole Menu() function again. Please help me fix this.
p.s. This is incomplete.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

int Menu();

int main()
{

    float currMoney = 0;
    float giveMoney = 0;

    float coke = 8.50;
    float fantaG = 9;
    float fantaO = 9;
    float creamS = 7;


    Menu();

    int Choice = Menu();
    system("cls");
    if(Choice == 1)
    {
        cout<< "Insert R"<< coke << endl;

        int pay = 0;
        cin>> pay;

        float returnA = pay - coke;

        if(returnA < 0)
        {
            returnA = -returnA;
            cout<< "you still owe R"<< returnA << "0" << endl;
        }
    }


}


int Menu()
{
    cout<< "[Drink machine v1.0]\n\n"<< endl;

    cout<< "[1]Coke -- R8,50"<< endl;
    cout<< "[2]Fanta grape -- R9,00" <<endl;
    cout<< "[3]Fanta orange -- R9,00"<< endl;
    cout<< "[4]Cream Soda -- R7,00"<< endl;

    int Choice = 0;
    cin>> Choice;

    return Choice;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason it's being called twice is because *you're calling it twice!*

```
Menu();               // first time

int Choice = Menu();  // second time
```

In the first call you don't capture the return value - so all it does it show the menu, ask for input, and then discard the result.

In the second call you show the menu again, ask for input, and then this time you capture the result, and action on that result.

From the look of it you want to remove the first call to `Menu()`

Answer (score 2):

You *are* calling it twice in the code

```
int main() {
    Menu();
    int Choice = Menu();
}
```